# Newsletter confirmation while subscribed on registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

**Newsletter confirmation is enabled** - user receives an e-mail message with link to agree subscribing to newsletter when he subscribes from newsletter form on homepage.

Unfortunately, on registration page when user checks checkbox he wants subscribe to newsletter, he subscribes to newsletter automatically without confirmation.

It makes possible to subscribe anyone.

Is there any option to enable confirmation when user subscribes from registration page?

Thanks.